# Calculating $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2}e^{\frac{k^2}{n^2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-sum

I'm trying to calculate the following limit:

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2}e^{\frac{k^2}{n^2}}$$

I tried getting to a form so I can use Riemann's sum but I can see which partition I should use.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to pull out the $1/n$ to get the form of a Riemann sum, and after that I really only see one choice for the partition?

Comment: Pick a $1/n$ out of the sum. And you will see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: This is
$$
\frac1n\sum \frac k n e^{(\frac k n)^2}.
$$
Can you see what function has this as a Riemann sum? ($x=\frac k n$)

Comment: I think I see it now. Should I calculate $\int_0^1 xe^{x^2}dx$?

Comment: That is the limit, yes.